# Treat the data collected through JSON api with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am collecting data provided by an API in JSON.

With the code below I can see that the data was collected inside Subscribe.

But outside of it, inside the .TS file itself I can not manipulate this data.

I tried to use the promise, but I think I did not use it correctly, because I also did not have a positive result.

How could I handle this data before presenting it on the screen?

```
getHour() {
this.hourService.getData()
  .subscribe(
    posts => this.posts = posts,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
   () => console.log(this.posts));     

  console.log(this.posts);
}

getData(): Observable<usersPerHour[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.uri)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9REOQ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulating the data"?

Do you want to change the data? If so, use the `map` function for `Observable`s.

Do you want to do something before the `subscribe` handler function is called? Use the `do` function for `Observable`s.

If your problem is the context of `this` in your handler function, this is because you're not using curly braces for your lambda function which means you lose the `this` context. You need to add curly braces or `bind` the handler function to `this` in order to do so.

Comment: Sorry Osmar, I don't speak Portuguese, but I managed to translate your comment so I understood what you wrote. Your comment still didn't answer my questions, what does "handle the data" mean, to you? Do you want to change it? If so, just use `map` before your `subscribe`. Please be more elaborate so I can write an actual answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant "manipulating the date", sorry for my English.

I updated the description, displaying the getData () function, where I have the Observables and the map.

Would I have to use everything in the same function?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

When I say manipulate, I would like, for example, to generate an average of hours.

Or add up the whole amount and then show the result on the screen. maybe show all the data on the screen too.

Comment: For the average of hours you can use the [`average` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/average.html) and for the sum of the amount you can use the [`sum` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sum.html).

Comment: But I can only do this within Subscribe.

How do I do this out of Subscribe?

Comment: As the documentation suggests, you do so before calling `subscribe`. What you get by calling `sum` or `average` is a new `Observable` which only emits the sum or the average (respectively) of the values **to be emitted** from the original `Observable` (the one on which you invoke `sum` or `average`).

Comment: Cool, I'm already seeing the documentation.

Thank you.

If I just want to show the data separately, can I use similar?

Comment: You can call `this.hourService.getData()` once and use the return value (an `Observable`) to create 2 new `Observable`s which you'll store in order to display them. Let's say, you store `this.hourService.getData()` as a variable called `hoursData$`. You can add a member called `averageHour$` which will be equal to `hoursData$.average()`, and another member called `sumHour$` which will be equal to `hoursData$.sum()`. Then subscribe to both and do whatever you need in the handler function :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You already achieved your goal when printing inside the subscription logic.

Since you are observing a subject, thus in a [asynchronous programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) paradigm, the call to the console.log just after the subscription is executed prior to the observable emitting an item.

Comment: I was thinking that.

So I could not use the data, because the execution of the function only ends after the console has already been executed.

Comment: You can use only once you have it. And this moment is not right after the subscription. Imagine T0 is the subscription, T1 is the console log, T2 is the data emitted in the subject. After T2 you have it defined and you can use it.